# Mongoose variable key name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, mongoose, schema-design

I have a `mongo` object and wish to access it via `mongoose` for my web app. The schema I've defined has an `Object` storing user ids and a 3-level value (yes, maybe or no).

e.g.

```
"user_info": {
    "<id_value_1>": "y",
    "<id_value_2>": "n"
}
```

The `id_value_*`s above are the users session ids so a long string of random characters. How can I create a `mongoose` `Schema` for this?

1. Would `user_info: {String, String}` work?
2. I could restructure it so that the `user_info` is an array of objects `{ "sessionid": "<value>", "value: "y"}`, which would be ok, is this the best option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll be better off if you avoid dynamic keys in your schema and go with your second idea of:

```
user_info: [{sessionid: String, value: String}]
```

You can use the [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) to update individual `user_info` array elements by `sessionid`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it's better to avoid dynamic keys? Is it just because mongoose can't handle it?

Comment: @ruX You can't index dynamic keys, they're awkward to build queries for, you can't define a useful Mongoose schema for them...

Answer (score 4):

You may try with Schema Type Mixed like this way

```
var user = new Schema({
   info:    [Schema.Types.Mixed]
 });

user.info = { any: { thing: 'i want' } };
user.markModified('info');
```

You can read more about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

After testing the above, I found that defining the schema as `user_info: { String: String }` is a valid way to do this (option 1 specified in the question).

Comment: I believe this option does not work, since I implemented this change the web app failed, so see the answer from @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0):

You may define objects and arrays in your schema. You may even combine them. For example, this is an array of objects:

```
var user = new Schema({
    foo: [ {
        address: {type: String},
        email: {type: String, unique: true}
    }],
    bar: [ "simple", "array" ]
});
```

Comment: My question was related to the fact that the key does not have a simple name like 'address', rather the key is generated in the code, but yes this is a valid way as per part 2. of my question